# Find intersection of data between rows and columns

Tags: data-mining, dataset, visualization, pandas, data-cleaning

Below is an Excel sheet with crops and countries. "1" means that the crop is grown in that country whiles "0" means it is not grown in that country.

I want to find where there is an intersection (as in I want to find similar crops that are grown in most of the countries or at least most of the countries.) How do I do this ?

[image: Snapshot of spreadsheet with crops and the countries they are grown in]

Answer (score 1):

Suppose that you want to know the name of countries with more than ten *Ginger*:

```
# read your data using pd.read_csv and specify appropriate inputs based on your excel file in a typical variable named csvFile and transpose it
csvFile = csvFile[csvFile['Ginger'] > 10]
```

Also if you want to see the countries with zero *Ginger*:

```
csvFile = csvFile[csvFile['Ginger'] == 0]
```